# Trouble understanding the quotient morphism of subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra

In my lecture notes that I'm studying right now for a course on Abstract Algebra, I was given the following proposition:

> Suppose $N\trianglelefteq G$ and let $\pi:G\to G/N$ be the quotient morphism. The $\pi$ induces a bijection, $$ \begin{align*} \Phi:\{\text{subgroups }H\leq G \text{ that contain }N\} &\longrightarrow \{\text{subgroups }\bar{H}\leq G/N\}  \end{align*} $$ such that $$ H\longmapsto \pi(H) = H/N. $$
> The inverse of $\Phi$ is given by $\Psi(\bar{H}):=\pi^{-1}(\bar{H})$.

My problem with this statement is the way that $\Psi$ is defined. It seems to assume that $\pi^{-1}$ exists, and although $\pi$ is certainly surjective, I have a hard time believing it's always injective. So why can we define $\Psi$ such that it's contingent on $\pi^{-1}$ if it's not necessarily a bijection? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, $\pi^{-1}$ denotes not an inverse function for $\pi$, but the *preimage* (or *inverse image*), which is defined for any function and takes subsets of the codomain to subsets of the domain (rather than acting on elements). Explicitly, given a function $\pi\colon A \to B$ and a subset $C \subseteq B$, we define
$$\pi^{-1}(C) = \{a \in A : \pi(a) \in C\}.$$
In your case, we have $A = G$, $B = G/N$, and $C = \bar{H}$, so $\pi^{-1}(\bar{H})$ is the subgroup of $G$ consisting of all elements of $G$ whose image under the quotient map $\pi$ is contained in the subgroup $\bar{H}$ of $G/N$.

(Also, indeed, the quotient map $\pi\colon G \to G/N$ is injective only in the trivial case where $N = \{1\}$.)